# driver for canon LBP6030

Tags: printing, ubuntu-drivers

We have Canon laser printer (Canon LBP6030) Connected in Windows. how to make connection with that printer through LAN. Please provide driver software.also mention how to install the driver software.

Comment: For 32bit Linux there are drivers available [here](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp6020.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(32-bit)) but there seems to be no support for Linux 64bit

Comment: It's 64 bit , what I have to do

Answer (score 4):

If you go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100595001.html to the Canon Asia site, you can download and SAVE what will be linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken.tar.gz which was issued on 14th Nov 2017. It is a comprehensive package that has rpm and debian drivers; in both **32bit** and **64bit** variants. **There is an install script that does all the work for you**.

To install: open a terminal; (hold the control and alt and t buttons down ..)

To paste the commands below into a terminal; right-click at the flashing text prompt in the terminal; and select PASTE from the menu that appears .

.. so copy each command below; one line at a time; and paste into the terminal and hit the ENTER key ..

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken.tar.gz
cd linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken
```

next comes the install script so watch the terminal as it runs, as it will likely ask you some questions .....

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

and that should 1) install the drivers and 2) register the printer with lpadmin so you can print from any programme ..

Comment: The printer in connected in windows machine. how to connect with that printer.

Answer (score 2):

The official US support driver can be download here

https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/laser-single-function/imageclass/lbp6030w#Z7_MQH8HIC0LOH520AUHT7ADHRMN6

Open a terminal then enter following commands

```
cd ~/Downloads

tar -zxvf linux-UFRIILT-drv-v150-usen.tar.gz

cd linux-UFRIILT-drv-v150-usen

sudo ./install.sh
```

continue with register printer in linux (Ubuntu)
you should see the printer in your system.

Good luck